# How to use MIDI keyboard with seq24

Tags: sound, jack, midi

I want to set some MIDI from a MIDI keyboard on a loop using a sequencer, and it seems like seq24 would be the simplest way to do this. However, seq24 doesn't show up in JACK connections, and I don't know how to connect my keyboard to it. It also doesn't play sound when I use the on-screen input (probably is related to not showing up in JACK). How do I fix it? thanks!

If another program is better, I'd use that too. I have qtractor and rosegarden installed, but I don't know how to loop things with those programs without copying and pasting..

Answer (score 0):

Try starting seq24 with the `-m` option or edit *$HOME/.seq24rc* and look for the `[manual-alsa-ports]` section. It should be set to 1.